# How can I see/access the revision history of a Drupal user in Drupal 9

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-views

How can see the revision history of a Drupal user.  I can see the history on content types, but I don't know how to access this same data for a Drupal user.  So if i am here
`user/13/edit` there is no **revisions** link.  Can this be turned on in Drupal9?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear - what to you mean by "revision (history) of a user"? The edits the user made (to content) or changes made to the user profile data of the user (e.g. when his "Full name" or phone number was changed, or whatever else you created as user profile fields)?

Answer (score 1):

After you turn on "revisions" as you said, you can go to /node/nodeID/revisions

[image: 1]

You don't need to create a view for that because drupal already have this page to show you each revision/change on your content types

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me - i turned revision on within the content type.  after that I created a view and when selecting fields, i was able to pick revision history items.  Worked nicely.